# Show that $\exp\circ\log = \operatorname{id}$ with Taylor series

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, taylor-expansion, power-series, exponential-function

Good evening!

We all know that $\exp(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ holds for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\log(x) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty (-1)^{j-1}\frac{(x-1)^j}{j}$ holds for $|x-1|<1$. Further, by definition, we have $$\exp\circ\log = \operatorname{id} \text{ }(*).$$

So, a "natural" question nobody asks seems to be: How can one prove $(*)$ by using the above Taylor expansions? Even though little to nothing could be gained from it, I am curious to see if someone can "elementarily" (i.e. without using further properties of $\exp$ and $\log$) prove
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{ \left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty (-1)^{j-1}\frac{(x-1)^j}{j} \right)^k}{k!}=x$$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $|x-1|<1$.

Comment: Your formula for log is not for $|x|<1$ but for $|x-1|<1.$

Comment: The power series for $\log x$ is for $|x-1|<1.$ $\log x$ isn't even defined for all $|x|<1.$

Comment: Better to try to show $\exp(\log(1+x))=1+x$ for $|x|<1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You're right, that would certainly simplify things.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for the link!

Comment: It's not true that "no one seems to be asking" this question, in fact variations of this question have been asked several times on math.SE. It's also not true that "little to nothing could be gained from it"; some of the proofs readily generalize to $x$ in a Banach algebra, say, while others tell you the combinatorial content of this identity (it is equivalent to the existence and uniqueness of cycle decomposition for permutations) which generalizes to many much less obvious identities, e.g. a generating function for the number of involutions, all sorts of stuff.

Comment: Here are two previous threads where I explain how to prove this using the existence and uniqueness theorems for ODEs: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852168/proving-that-the-exponential-and-logarithm-functions-for-matrices-are-inverses-o/3852183#3852183, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486706/how-do-i-show-that-formal-logarithm-is-the-inverse-of-the-formal-exponential/2486731#2486731